# How do I save in Mini Ninjas?

Tags: nintendo-wii, mini-ninjas

I'm trying to save, but I can't find the "save" button. Where exactly is the save button?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is one per se - saving is done via autosaving and when exit to main menu.